# resursive function not incrementing as expected - python/django

Tags: python, django, recursion, tree, nodes

I'm creating a tree app using Django models.  Basically a user inputs the names of different nodes, and if a node is connected to another, a recursive function adds 1 to the parent node's "nodes" property.  As soon as I add nodes that increase a parents' total to >2, it stops incrementing and stays at two.  Here's the code:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
    nodes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The user inputs text.  For example, let's say a user enters the following:

```
"animal(dog)"
"dog(golden retriever)"  # animal nodes should be 2 (and it is)
"golden retriever(old yeller)" # animal nodes should now be 3 but it remains 2
```

This should generate a tree of this structure:

```
     animal   (3 nodes)
   /         
dog      (2 nodes)      
  |
golden retriever   (1 node)
  | 
 old yeller  (0 nodes)
```

Somehow the node_ancestors method functions correctly only at first.  Any ideas on what's going wrong in my views?

```
def node_ancestors(node):  

    ancestor = node.parent 

    if ancestor != None: 

        ancestor.nodes += 1
        print ancestor, " just added a node.   it now has %d nodes. " % (ancestor.nodes)
        node.save()
        node_ancestors(ancestor)

def index(request):
    nodes = Node.objects.all()
    node_names = [a.name for a in nodes]

if request.method == 'POST':  
    node_string = request.POST.get('get_node')
    print node_string
    index = node_string.find('(')
    parent = node_string[0:index]
    child = node_string[index+1:len(node_string)-1]

    if parent not in moment_names and child not in node_names:
        parent = Node(name=parent, nodes=1)
        parent.save()
        child = Node(name=child, parent=parent)
        child.save()
        print "parent is", parent
        print "child is", child
        print "parent nodes: ", parent.nodes
        print "child nodes: ", child.nodes

    elif parent in node_names and child not in node_names:
        parent_model = nodes.get(name=parent)

        node_ancestors(parent_model)  # adds 1 to all nodes superior to parent node

        child = Node(name=child, parent=parent_model)

        child.save()


    elif parent not in node_names and child in node_names:
        parent = Node(name=parent, nodes=child_model.nodes+1)
        parent.save()
        print "parent is", parent

return render(request, 'nodes_app/index.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these kind of things, you could maybe use Django MPTT (http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/), it is designed to build tree models and has a [lot of built-in methods](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html) to get/display ancestors/children.

Here is a simple example built from the code you gave :

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Species(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

dog = Species()
dog.name = "Dog"
dog.save()

golden = Species()
golden.name = "Golden Retriever"
golden.parent = dog
golden.save()

old = Species()
old.name = "Old Yeller"
old.parent = golden
old.save()


print(dog.level)    # 0
print(golden.level) # 1
print(old.level)    # 2

ancestors = old.get_ancestors(include_self=True)

for each species in ancestors:
    print(species.name)

# Dog
# Golden Retriever
# Old Yeller
```